# how to combine two lists and assign keys to them

Tags: r, list

I have 2 list:

```
comb_test <- list(c(7, 8))

col_type_list <- list(c("bin", "bin"))
```

I would like to get a new list that would look like this:

```
common.list <- list(list(id = 7, type = "bin"), list(id = 8, type = "bin"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `lapply` through the length of one of your vectors...

```
lapply(1:length(comb_test[[1]]), function(x) list(id = comb_test[[1]][[x]], type = col_type_list[[1]][[x]]))

[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] 7

[[1]]$type
[1] "bin"


[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] 8

[[2]]$type
[1] "bin"
```

Comment: `mapply` or `Map` are more suitable for this case, i.e. `Map(\(x, y) list(id = x, type = y), comb_test[[1]], col_type_list[[1]])`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `purrr::transpose()`. If your data consists of vectors embedded in length-one lists, as in your example:

```
library(purrr)

comb_test <- list(c(7, 8))
col_type_list <- list(c("bin", "bin"))

transpose(list(id = comb_test[[1]], type = col_type_list[[1]]))
```

If you’re instead working with flattened lists, you can omit `[[1]]`:

```
comb_test <- list(7, 8)
col_type_list <- list("bin", "bin")

transpose(list(id = comb_test, type = col_type_list))
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] 7

[[1]]$type
[1] "bin"


[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] 8

[[2]]$type
[1] "bin"
```